# Object Oriented method structure - What is allowed?

Tags: java, oop

This might seem like a strange question, but bear with me. I was looking to find out if there are any sort of structural specifications whereby I could deduce what kind of programming constructs are permissible within the method of an object-oriented class (preferably Java). For example, in a Java method, you can define local variables, object references, try/catch blocks etc... but you cannot, for example, define a constructor or another method. Does this make sense?

Why do I want to find this information out? The reason is that I wish to take a method and analyse it and print out any declared local variable names, any declared reference names, any instance variables that are used in the method etc... So, ultimately, I was wondering if there are any structural specifications out there on the web that might tell me what you are allowed to include in a Java method (or an object-oriented method). I suppose this is tantamount to a grammar that you would use for a domain specific language.

Comment: Of course such a specification exists: You'll find what you're looking for in the grammar of the Java programming language. (A grammar essentially defines what input is considered valid.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you perhaps be looking for the [grammar](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/syntax.html#18.1) used in the Java reference implementation?

Comment: Hi Tim. Yes, that will do the trick. I can look through that and deduce what is syntactically acceptable within a method body.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try looking into the [Reflection API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) which will allow you to print out and analyze classes, their methods, and fields.

Comment: Hi Cam. I am going to use the Soot analysis framework as it will allow me to statically perform analysis of my java source code at build time. The reflection API allows for introspection at run-time only, no? Correct me if I'm wrong. Cheers

Comment: @Joeblackdev: My apologies! Re-reading your question it is clear that you wanted static-time analysis. The reflection API is for run-time only. Good luck with your project :)